# Detect button click or touch from java webview android

Tags: android, html, webview

In my activity I have webview and top of WebView there is a RelativeLayout which contains edittext and button. This RelativeLayout has to open/close when user touch on webview. The problem is that I can't detect where user touch in html content, for instance if user click the button in HTML , RelativeLayout shoudn't open but if user touch blank area in html then RelativeLayout will open. How can I detect user's touch is not in any touchable or clickable area in html content ?

HTML pages are not in my control so I couldn't build jafascriptinterface, I has to do in with Webview.

Comment: can you update your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
event.preventDefault();
```

if your menu uses a jquery function that toggles the areas visible.. 
ex. if you have an click function..

```
$(".menu-item").click( 
  function () {
   event.preventDefault();
   yourcodethattogglesmenu
  }
);
```

Show your code first in the future, will help us understand and give a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, you want to show a native view (RelativeLayout) once a specific HTML element is clicked.
The only way to trigger JAVA code from HTML content is the JavascriptInterface. If you do not control the HTML stuff you are out.